# Run Mysql Test Suite -- Test needs debug binaries

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I built Mysql 5.7.17 from source code downloaded from Github but I couldn't run some of the test cases in mysql-test directory because they need debug binaries. How do I include debug binaries? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure you're on a good path, here... do you have a reason for not using the official binaries?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the response, Michael. Yes, I am working to customize Mysql code so I have to build it from source code. I actually figured it out. Running cmake with  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug did the trick.